Why is it not showing my Structured Data Markup?
If you perform the search matthews site:tradewindsstudios.us you get 2 results. Both results have the Structured Data Markup - and Rich Tests Results show both as having the correct metadata.
So why does Google not show the metadata on the right?

What are you looking to display in search results?

@A_Patterson I'm expecting it to show the structured data - as this test does. TIA

@A_Patterson Am I wrong in assuming it will always show the structured data for the first search result in Google? Or do other things need to be true for it to do so? TIA

It has been my experience that on page content will be stronger signals to Google than schema or anything else. And remember, these are only signals. Google and other providers will always reserve final say as to what they believe your SERP should be. And the result could potentially look different for different keywords and terms.

And I think you are referring to Knowledge Panels for organizations. Again, they are great signals but they reserve the right to show whatever. If the site is newer or doesn't have a lot of organic traffic, they might not use the resources required to present knowledge panels or other interactive elements.

@A_Patterson If you write your comments all up as an answer, happy to select it. thanks

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

From my experience, the best signals to send to Google are those that appear on the page (content, headings, page titles, even meta description). While structured data is a great thing to add to enhance the signals you are already sending, there are probably stronger ones that Google will take into account first.
And the biggest thing to remember is that even after we do all this SEO work, Google still reserves the right to display whatever in the SERP. So if it feels something needs to be different, don't be surprised if it doesn't appear the way you crafted your signals.
For the Knowledge Panel (and other rich items in the SERP), there is no guarantee that your efforts will result in those items being seen/leveraged by Google. I would recommend combing over their documentation on rich snippets and double check you are following their recommendations if you are looking to appear in them.
